# El Capitan: (Text) Cursor moves during my typing

Tags: cursor

Have you notice**sor is all of the sudden in a different place** that strange thing when you type **cur**...?

It's super annoying when writing longer text. Or even if not (wtf Apple?). I found [some solutions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4256492?tstart=0) but they are from 2011 and suggest things like replacing the battery or playing with "PRAM". There has to be something better, right?

Or, this looked good, uut it's no longer an option in Sys Preferences.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Ignore accidental trackpad input is no longer an option because it's enabled by default fwiw.

Comment: Do you have any other input devices connected? My Wacom tablet sometimes detects random wires touching it as touch input.

Answer (score 1):

Even though Apple says ignore accidental trackpad input is enabled by default, this does not seem to be the case in Yosemite/El Capitan, as several users have pointed out on the [Apple support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29200584?start=120&tstart=0).

To address this issue, I made a program that disables the trackpad for a short time when typing on the keyboard. Take a look here and let me know if it works for you (I've only tested it on El Capitan 10.11.6 so far): https://github.com/thesyntaxinator/TouchGuard